# Subsurface color not showing

Tags: color-management

[image: OP Supplied image of their shader setup]

Hi, so I’ve been trying to tweak the color of a texture applied object by adjusting the subsurface color seen in the picture but it’s not changing anything, can someone help me with this? Thank you!

And btw if any more info is needed please feel free to ask and I will add it asap

Comment: Just under *base color* is a slider called *subsurface* turn that up. I usually start with 0.1

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!